# PyCharm: Python template language is stuck on jinja2

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

The PyCharm parses is complaining about all the colons in my Django template:

[image]

The error message it gives is "Expected }}".

This started happening after I created a **separate** project that has jinja2 templates. That is, it was working fine before, but is now complaining about those colons. So, it is probably something I did to the settings.

I do have the Python Template Language set to Django:

[image]

I don't know what else to check.

I just noticed, that the icon next to `testfile.html` is "J2". This should be HTML. I think the problem is that changing the template language back to Django is not doing anything. PyCharm still thinks it is a jinja2 template. Any help?

Comment: Looks as if `testfile.html` (or `*.html`) pattern is associated with *Jinja 2 Template* file type. Please see the list of patterns registered for this fiole type in **File | Settings | Editor | File Types, Jinja 2 Template** - do you have any `html` patterns there?

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks! That was the answer to my problem. Once I removed that association it fixed all the problems.